# Pythonic way to randomly assign pandas dataframe entries

Tags: python, pandas, random

Suppose we have a data frame

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

In [2]: df
Out[3]:
     A   B   C   D
0   45  88  44  92
1   62  34   2  86
2   85  65  11  31
3   74  43  42  56
4   90  38  34  93
5    0  94  45  10
..  ..  ..  ..  ..
```

How can I randomly replace x% of *all* entries with a value, such as `None`?

```
In [4]: something(df, percent=25)
Out[5]:
     A   B   C   D
0   45  88  None  92
1   62  34   2  86
2   None  None  11  31
3   74  43  None  56
4   90  38  34  None
5    None  94  45  10
..  ..  ..  ..  ..
```

I've found information about sampling particular axes, and I can imagine a way of randomly generating integers within the dimensions of my data frame and setting those equal to `None`, but that doesn't feel very Pythonic.

- Edit: forgot 'way' in title

Answer (score 4):

You could combine `DataFrame.where` and `np.random.uniform`:

```
In [37]: df
Out[37]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  2  2
1  2  2  0  3
2  3  0  0  3
3  0  2  3  1

In [38]: df.where(np.random.uniform(size=df.shape) > 0.3, None)
Out[38]: 
      A  B     C     D
0     1  0     2  None
1     2  2     0     3
2     3  0  None  None
3  None  2     3  None
```

It's not the most concise, but gets the job done.

Note though that you should ask yourself whether you really *want* to do this if you still have computations to do.  If you put None in a column, then pandas is going to have to use the slow object dtype instead of something fast like int64 or float64.

Comment: I like random choice with true and false

Comment: Thank you, I'm not actually interested in substituting None, I'm interested in substituting a random set of nucleotides (A, C, G, or T) in a series of DNA sequences with 'N'. I'm not sure if this would change your answer. I ran a few tests trying to do this by randomly selecting integers within the dimensions and it rapidly becomes inefficient.

Comment: @IanGilman You are using a DataFrame of individual letters representing nucleotide sequences? You should probably make sure you aren't using the `object` dtype already. That will be space and time inefficient, if you know each value is a single letter, you can reduce your memory usage to a fraction of what it takes with `object` dtype